# ejabberd compile error from source

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I want to compile ejabberd from source code and follow these steps:

> 1. download from git.
> 2. ./configure
> 3. make
> 4. sudo make install
> 5. sudo ejabberdctl satrt

But these steps gives this error. any one help me please.

```
2015-09-23 15:24:51.177 [info] <0.7.0> Application p1_xml exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,xml,{function_clause,[{filename,join,[{error,bad_name},"lib"],[{file,"filename.erl"},{line,407}]},{filename,join,1,[{file,"filename.erl"},{line,394}]},{xml,init,1,[{file,"src/xml.erl"},{line,51}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}},{xml_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
2015-09-23 15:24:56.339 [info] <0.7.0> Application lager started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.347 [info] <0.7.0> Application crypto started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.357 [info] <0.7.0> Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.369 [info] <0.7.0> Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.369 [info] <0.7.0> Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.378 [info] <0.7.0> Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.382 [info] <0.7.0> Application p1_yaml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.391 [info] <0.7.0> Application p1_tls started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-09-23 15:24:56.394 [error] <0.114.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.114.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching filename:join({error,bad_name}, "lib") line 407 in gen_server:init_it/6 line 352
2015-09-23 15:24:56.397 [error] <0.113.0> Supervisor xml_sup had child undefined started with xml:start_link() at undefined exit with reason no function clause matching filename:join({error,bad_name}, "lib") line 407 in context start_error
2015-09-23 15:24:56.398 [critical] <0.39.0>@ejabberd:exit_or_halt:133 failed to start application 'p1_xml': {error,
                                       {{shutdown,
                                         {failed_to_start_child,xml,
                                          {function_clause,
                                           [{filename,join,
                                             [{error,bad_name},"lib"],
                                             [{file,"filename.erl"},
                                              {line,407}]},
                                            {filename,join,1,
                                             [{file,"filename.erl"},
                                              {line,394}]},
                                            {xml,init,1,
                                             [{file,"src/xml.erl"},{line,51}]},
                                            {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},
                                              {line,328}]},
                                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},
                                              {line,239}]}]}}},
                                        {xml_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a transient issue in the development version / repository.

Dependency has been adjusted. If you restart from scratch with HEAD of master, it should just work fine.

Comment: It seems it is already answered + it is not good practice to comment on other ticket to ask for help on your own, I think.

Comment: Yes sir, Understood. I am sorry.